# run php script every 1 minute whithout cron job

Tags: php

I get following solution to execute php script every 1 min but it does not work.can you find error or any new solution?

```
<?php

  while (true)
  {

    echo "hi";
    sleep(60));
  }
?>
```

Comment: Note: You should simply use `sleep($interval * 60);` instead of `sleep($interval*60-(time()-$now));` as `time()-$now` will always be `0`.

Comment: What does not work? Do you get an error, does it stop running, something else?

Comment: What do you mean does not work? For me it iterates through the loop every 1 minute

Comment: hi i edited code like this...it keeps loading the page

Comment: If you are running your script via a webserver, e.g. Apache2, there might be a timeout for scripts configured, usually about 300 seconds, see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/en/mod/core.html#timeout

Comment: .after time out it will print all echo..cant it behave like it print 'hi' after 1 minute it will print 'hi'? rather than print all echo at timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with AJAX
Jquery AJAX Docs : http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <title>asd</title>
 </head>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function theAjaxCall(){
  $.ajax({ 
   url: 'your_php_file.php',// set your config
   data: {action: 'test'},
   type: 'post',
   success: function(output) {
    $("body").append(output);
   }
  });
 }
 $(document).ready(function(){
  setInterval(theAjaxCall, 60000);//every 1 min
 });
 </script>
 <body>
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please change setTimeout() to setInterval()..and it works properly..thank you for answer :) ..do this change and i will aprove the answer.